# Machine Dependent Corrupted Double Linked List Error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am making a game for my software engineering class and my group is experiencing an odd issue. We create items as a doubley linked list in the level and as as soon as we touch an item we call delete on that item. But when I touch the item pointed to by itemHead in the linked list I get a corrupted double linked list error. For some reason the itemHead next seems to be pointing to some garbage memory.

This wouldn't be so odd if it was on every machine but it only seems to happen on some of the laptops in my group. We all compared our specs, we are all running 64bit linux mint, we all have the same version of g++, and we all did a fresh clone off of gitHub so we all have the same version of the game. And we can not seem to get why the segfault happens on only some machines.

If you would like to look at the code post your gitHub account name and we will give you access. But simply telling why this might happen should point us in the right direction to figure out how this is messing up.

Here is how we are creating the items in a circular doubley linked list, detecting the item collision with the character, and how we are deleting. in that order.

```
Items *createDiamond() {

        Items *it = new Diamond;
        it->next = itemHead;
        if (itemHead != NULL)
            itemHead->prev = it;
        itemHead = it;
        nItems++;
        return it;
    }    
void checkItemCollision(Game * g) {
    Items *item = g->itemHead;
    while(item!=NULL) {
      int itemY = item->getCenterY();
      int itemX = item->getCenterX();
      int itemH = item->getHeight();
      int itemW = item->getWidth();
    //top
    if ( (g->player.getPosX() + g->player.getWidth() > itemX
                && g->player.getPosX() -g->player.getWidth() < itemX )
            && (g->player.getPosY() - g->player.getHeight() <= itemY )
            && (g->player.getPosY() + g->player.getHeight() >= itemY) ) 
    {
        if (item->type == "diamond") {
            g->player.addToScore(500);
        } else if (item->type == "heart") {
            g->player.addToScore(200);
            g->player.incHealth();
        }
        if (item->type == "dagger"){
            g->player.setDagActive();
            g->player.hasDaggers = true;
            g->player.daggers =+ 7;
        }
        if (item->type == "axe"){
            g->player.setAxeActive();
            g->player.hasAxes = true;
            g->player.axes =+ 7;
        }
        Items *saveItem = item;
        g->deleteItem(item);
        item = saveItem;
    }
    item = item->next;
}
```

}

```
void deleteItem(Items *node) {
        if(node->prev == NULL){enter code here`
            if (node->next == NULL){
                itemHead = NULL;
            } 
            else {
                node->next->prev = NULL;
                itemHead = node->next;
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (node->next == NULL){
                node->prev->next = NULL;
            } 
            else {
                node->prev->next = node->next;
                node->next->prev = node->prev;
            }
        }
        free(node);
        nItems--;
        node = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: we cant really help you without the code. Could you perhaps post the relevant code here?

Comment: Also the machines that are experiencing issues don't always spit out the same error when we compile. Sometimes it is a segfault, other times it is a "double free or corruption", or "corrupted double linked list".

Comment: @FSmash `This wouldn't be so odd if it was on every machine but it only seems to happen on some of the laptops in my group.`  You are writing C++ code.  Any error where you are using pointers incorrectly results in *undefined behavior*.  That means that *anything* can happen, including the program not experiencing any external issues.  It also means the program may run today, not run tomorrow, work on 100 machines and crash on machine 101, etc.?  This has nothing to do with "machine dependence" -- your program has bugs.

Comment: @FSmash How about posting `Items`?  As a matter of fact, code snippets aren't really going to help a lot.  Your error could have occurred anywhere in your program, and you're just posting where the code finally falls apart.  Better to post a complete, but small program that duplicates the error.

Comment: Or better yet, post complete program in ideone.com.

Comment: @FSmash  `free(node);`  What the heck...?  Now you really do need to post `Items`.

Comment: Does it compiler with zero warnings? Turn the warnings up to their maximum level and you will see errors. But I am betting that Diamond does not have a constructor that initializes its members.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing uninitialized memory may cause effects like these. Usually in C++ standard this is specified by "Unidentified behavior", so everything might happen, from working correctly to seg-faults. I suggest you start your program through memory validator.. Valgrind seems good candidate.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is this:

```
 Items *it = new Diamond;
```

Then you do this in your `deleteItem` function:

```
 free(node);
```

where `node` is of type `Item*`.

You are mixing allocation and deallocation routines.  When you allocate with `new`, you must use `delete`, not `free`.  You use `free` on functions in the `malloc` family (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, etc).  By mixing up your allocation / deallocation routines, you introduced *undefined behavior* in your application.

That line should be this:

`delete node`

Now even with that change, this may not guarantee that your program will work.  If you made an error like this, more than likely you may have other issues with your code.

For example, this may have several things wrong with it:

```
  if (item->type == "diamond")
```

and similar lines.

If `type` is a `std::string`, then it's ok (and probably is a reason for your seg fault earlier when you called `free` instead of `delete`).  If it's a `char *` that is dynamically allocated, then not only is this the wrong way to compare char arrays for equality, your `Item` type may not have followed the `rule of 3`, thus causing undefined behavior if used in a copy.

Another issue that could cause a problem:

```
Items *it = new Diamond;
```

Now, assuming that `Diamond` is derived from `Items`, and since you are deleting `Items` (even though your original code is wrong), the `Items` class **must** have a virtual destructor declared (even if it's an empty virtual destructor).

The reason is that you are (or will be) calling `delete` using an `Items` pointer, which is the base class.  It is (again) **undefined behavior** to issue a call to `delete` on a base class pointer through a derived class if the base class does not have a virtual destructor.  So make sure that `Items` has a virtual destructor.

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue literally was we forgot to make our base Item Class virtual. We did that for every other class but just completely overlooked this one. And the issue with with the char pointer was also giving us problems but we switched to a string like you said.